# JPA/Hibernate: Map many-to-many relationship when join table has own primary key

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have three tables with simple structure:

```
pub [id, name]
days [id, name]
pub_days [id, pub_id, days_id]
```

For some unholy reason, somebody thought that compound identity for **pub_days** table (that would be pub_id + days_id) is not enough and added own primary key. I can't change it now, other and larger system depends on that. #sigh

I am trying to map this to Hibernate with standard `@ManyToMany` JPA annotation like so (I omitted getters, setters, @Entitiy annotations and other clutter):

```
class Pub {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "pub_days",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pub_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "days_id")})
    @OrderBy("id")
    private List<Day> pubOpeningDays;
}

class Day {
    @Id Long id;
    String name.
}
```

when I execute following code:

```
Day day = repository.find(Day.class, id);
pub.getPubOpeningDays().add(day);
repository.persist(pub);
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PUB"."pub_days"."id")
```

Sadly, that makes perfect sense, because I haven't mapped that ID anywhere. The thing is, I don't even want to. I want it to be generated, but not sure how do I overcome this issue with `@ManyToMany` mapping. Any ideas?

Comment: I think of creating a pojo class having attribute from both these classes and have its own pk which can be generated using any existing jpa strategy.

Comment: Would I need to change my mapping then?

Comment: In the both classes @ManyToMany will be there but with this new entity. Further more I see "CascaseType.ALL" which should be avoided.

Comment: Not sure if I understand this correctly, but I certainly don't want to have List of PubDay in Pub, I just want list of Day-s. If you can demonstrate this with code that'd be helpful!

Comment: ok, lets say you have two classes A and B, you create a middle man CD now CD will have many to many with both A and B. and CD will have its own PK.

Comment: ok, but A only has List of B-s, right?

Comment: Ended up with implementing middle table. you were the first to help, feel free to post answer so I can accept it.

Comment: No, A will have list of CD and B will have a list of CD, when you want to fetch A from instance of B you need to write a query for that something like SELECT * FROM A WHERE A.CD.b_id='SOME ID THAT YOU PROVIDED' Now this query can be jpql or native query using JPA to retrieve you data, I will post my answer as soon as i get some time :) thank you for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is like I mentioned in my comments you can create a separate entity CD which will in turn connect with two classes A and B, Now relationship would be many to many between A and B, and hence A (many to many) CD (many to many) B. Now as per your requirement whenever you need to fetch the instance of A or B, what you can do is simply fire a query in the DB with proper parameters i.e id of a or id of b this will help you get your required result.

Answer (score 0):

I only see two choices, either you change your mapping to a list of PubDay as samwise-gamgee told you in the comments or you add a trigger on insert on table pub_days which set a value for the column id if it is null (it could be using a sequence). But this approach depends on the features supported by your DB.

Comment: Ok, sadly, this was the way to go. I had to map linking entity :-/ For those interested in more details, I got myself book 'Java Persistence with Hibernate' and there is paragraph with exactly same problem - in my version it's 7.2.3 Adding columns to join tables.